# Transaction timeout for log process with EJB timer service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, jta

I'm using EJB to create scraping server. I have JTA Transaction Timeout problem when I'm using timer server like this:

```
@Schedule(persistent=false, minute="*", hour="*")
public void startBaidu() {
    // 1) Get some data about URL from database

    // 2) GET THE RESULTS FROM URL BY SELENIUM

    // 3) Store the results to database
}
```

Step 1,3 just take several milliseconds but step 2 takes 1 2 minuets!!! Is there any way to have JTA advantages and also do something about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the long times for step 2 aren't simply due to how Selenium functions? It may be worth researching alternative solutions, or creating your own more efficient replacement.

Alternatively, you can increase the timeout (although obviously this isn't ideal) in your config.xml, specifically this section:

```
   <JTA
    MaxUniqueNameStatistics="5"
    TimeoutSeconds="300"
    RecoveryThresholdMillis="150000" 
    MaxResourceUnavailableMillis="900000" 
    MaxResourceRequestOnServer="60" 
    MaxXACallMillis="180000" 
   />
```

(from [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13731/trxcon.htm#i1045637))

Answer (score 0):

Timeout problems occur in @Singleton or @Stateful EJB. If this is the case, and the transaction needs to be thread safe, consider:

```
@Schedule(persistent=false, minute="*", hour="*")
@AccessTimeout(SOME_MORE_MINUTES)
public void startBaidu() {
    // 1) Get some data about URL from database

    // 2) GET THE RESULTS FROM URL BY SELENIUM

    // 3) Store the results to database
}
```

If the method is thread-safe (can be access concurrently) so that no thread holds the lock for mere reading execution

```
@Schedule(persistent=false, minute="*", hour="*")
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public void startBaidu() {
    // 1) Get some data about URL from database

    // 2) GET THE RESULTS FROM URL BY SELENIUM

    // 3) Store the results to database
}
```